# Opposition of localizedStringFromDate: dateStyle: timeStyle:

Tags: objective-c, localization, nsdate, nsdateformatter

When I format a date via:

```
[NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:date dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle]];
```

save it somewhere, then try to access it, i get a NSString. How to get it as a NSDate?

BTW: **I want a method where i put NSDateFormatterStyle as argument.** Otherwise it will be wrong- in different locale it will be saved as different string, so formatting it as

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yy/MM/dd"];
```

or any other options of this kind - will create an error. Or at least i think so ;). 
Thanks for any responses.

Comment: So you want to save the `NSDate` (which you already have) rather than the `NSString`?

Comment: I do not have NSDate - i saved it somewhere (lets say to the plist) and now want a NSDate not NSString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSDateFormatter returns a NSString representation of the NSDate object.  NSDate is format insensitive, meaning it isn't tied to some locale, it's actually stored as a number.  You use the NSDateFormatter to present that numerical value as a localized representation.

To convert a NSString back to an NSDate you can use something like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yy/MM/dd"];
NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString: dateString];
```

Comment: No, because i store NSString- so i've lost already NSDate. My NSDate was localized to xx-xx-xx format, so i cant use setDateFormat as you wrote - it is different in different locales. As you wrote- NSDate is format insensitive but NSString returned from localizedStringFromDate already is.

Comment: Did you happen to save the locale along with the date string?

Comment: It doesn't matter in case of my code, but indeed, i saved locale with date. This wouldn't be a clean solution, but i did it exceptionally - because of some purposes.

Comment: If you want to read it back from a string, you do need to know what format it was localized to in the first place. Otherwise "01/02/03" could mean January 2, 2003, or February 1, 2003, or February 3, 2001. Is it too late to change your storage format? If your code isn't already in production, you'll have much better luck serializing the NSDate object instead of storing the string; the file format should be locale-agnostic. Otherwise, Richard's solution, using the stored locale, is the only way to get it back.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to store the NSDate in a way that can be perfectly parsed both ways. In that case I'd recommend storing it as an ISO8601 date, and you'll need to use an nsdateformatter more custom-like to do that. There are plenty of libraries/categories out there on github or stackoverflow to help you.

Comment: The question is more than 1 year old. However the correct answer is: one should store not parsed string from date, but real date object. After reading from database you can parse it to formatted string.

Comment: He said he saved it as a string. There is no 'real date object' here -- the example of plists do not support that as a primitive.